# Can I use Azure CustomTemplate Push notifications with "content-available" to update iOS app in the background?

Tags: ios, azure, push-notification, notifications, azure-notificationhub

Is it possible to send an Apple-specific tag in an Azure NotificationHub notification custom template? I would like to send "content-available":1 to an app without switching the server to send native notifications, but I can't figure out how.

I have an iOS app using Azure Notification Hub's custom templates to send push notifications.

My template works well, until now, when I have a new type of push message where I want the app to fetch info in the background.

I know how to do this on native iOS. If I subscribe to native notifications in my app and test send this as an apple native notification from Azure:

```
{"aps":{ "content-available":1} [ other parameters...] }
```

Then the application (didReceiveRemoteNotification, fetchCompletionHandler) function gets called in my App delegate, and I can use the other parameters from the native notification to get the info, even if the app is closed or in the background.

I have two problems trying to do this in a template though. First, I can't figure out w**here to put the content-available parameter in the custom template**.

Second, I can't subscribe to a template if I mention that parameter because "content-available" has a "-".

```
 MyHub!.registerTemplateWithDeviceToken(mobiledeviceToken!, name: "none", jsonBodyTemplate: "{\"aps\": {\"alert\":\"$(message)\",\"content-available\":\"$(content-available)\"}", expiryTemplate: "", tags: tags)
```

I get this error:

```
 PM</Detail></Error>" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Fail to perform registration operation. Response:<Error><Code>400</Code><Detail>Property name is content-available. Only ASCII-7 alphanumeric characters and '_' are permitted in the property name.
```

How can I send this parameter in a custom template, so that an iOS app can see it, and how do I subscribe to that template?

Or, do I have to switch to native notifications?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you should use `\"#(content_available)\"` instead of `\"$(content-available)\"`. Notice that "-" is not alphanumeric character and also "#" will result `"content-available":1` appears in actual payload while "$" would make `"content-available":"1"` which you don't want.

[Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn530748.aspx) you can find a nice article about NH templates.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. It helped me to resolve this issue with registering template. However I am not able to send notification to NotificationHub from backend. I am using this method "hub.SendNotificationAsync(TemplateNotification)". Could you share your solutions? I tried some scenarios mentioned on stackoverflow, but nothing worked. Thnx.

Answer (score 0):

@efimovandr's answer is correct but more steps are needed.

1. From Notification Hub API: Register Custom Template using `\"#(content_available)\"`. Now in notification hub, I found this will be a required field due to parsing exceptions that will now occur if not included. Although old registrations will work fine, which means it is backwards compatible depending on how you do your rollout.
2. From Notification Hub: it seems you actually **use the underscore**, and instead of a boolean [true/false] you must use "1", "0", 1 or 0 to avoid a parsing exception.

   `{ "alert" : "any", "content_available" : "1" }`
3. From Notification Hub API: Then when sending from (4.1.0) `Microsoft.Azure.NotificationHubs.NotificationHubClient.SendTemplateNotificationAsync(IDictionary<string, string> notification, string tagExpression)` method you **use the dash** instead of an underscore like this: `notification.Add("content_available","1")`.
4. From Mobile Application Code: If you are using Xamarin.iOS, when you are receiving in your AppDelegate.cs you **use the dash** again:

   ```
    var silentKey = new NSString("content-available");
    if (aps.ContainsKey(silentKey))
    {
      var val = aps.ObjectForKey(silentKey).ToString();

      if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(val) && val == "1")
      {
        // Silent Notification has been received!
      }
    }
   ```

Hope this resolves someone else's issue as this took me a week of tinkering!